# Find most frequent value but when there is a tie, choose the most recent in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, window-functions

So let's say I have some data like this:

```
ID  value  date
001     A  2015-12-06
001     A  2015-12-07
001     A  2015-12-08
002     B  2015-12-09
002     C  2015-12-10
003     A  2015-12-11
003     B  2015-12-12
002     B  2015-12-13
004     D  2015-12-13
004     R  2015-12-13
```

I want to find the `value` that appears most frequently for each ID. But when there is a tie, take the most recent date's value.

Expected Output:

```
ID  value
001     A
002     B
003     B
004     R
```

You may notice in the case of `004` there is the same date AND same ID during a tie. In this case, you can use the lower row entry.

Comment: It is not clear why in `004` `R` should be taken. `D` and `R` occur both times 1 and both are on `2015-12-13` -> so why is `R` the one with the most recent date?

Comment: @TarJae at that point, it is by row number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(date == max(date)) %>%
  summarise(value = value[1])
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>      ID value
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 A    
#> 2     2 B    
#> 3     3 B    
#> 4     4 D
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Good answer, but this is not the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**, after clarification OP. See comments: Here is the version that gives the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(ID, value, date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(date == max(date) & row_number() >1) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-n, -date)
```

```
     ID value
  <int> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     2 B    
3     3 B    
4     4 R
```

**First answer:**
Note group 0004 has ties and no most recent date, therefore both values are kept in the dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(ID, value, date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(date == max(date)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-n)
```

```
  ID    value date      
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 0001  A     2015-12-08
2 0002  B     2015-12-13
3 0003  B     2015-12-12
4 0004  D     2015-12-13
5 0004  R     2015-12-13
```